# Using wiifi_ddwrt Package

Tags: ros, wifi, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to work with the wifi_ddwrt Package on indigo. But, Im having trouble.

First I installed the Package by giving the Source in the terminal:

git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/wifi_ddwrt.git

After that I tried to execute the nodes (analysis, ddwrt, etc ) :

~/catkin_ws$ rosrun wifi_ddwrt analysis

and an error occured:

1. ```
           ImportError: cannot import name  pr2_msgs
   ```

and after I installed std_msgs

2. ```
           ImportError: cannot import name AccessPoint
   ```

Is there anything that Im doing wrong?  Would you guide me through the installation and execution of the Package/nodes?

Thank you in advance for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211561/using-wiifi_ddwrt-package/) by [KS](https://answers.ros.org/users/22835/ks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to install the pr2_msgs package: http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_msgs

Either `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pr2-msgs` or clone https://github.com/pr2/pr2_common.git

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0